# SQL: combine update with group-by?

Tags: sql, group-by, hsqldb

I've got two tables:

`events`:

```
mac | na
----------
abc | (null)
abc | (null)
def | (null)
```

`enrichments`:

```
mac | na  | timestamp
---------------------
abc | na1 | 1
abc | na2 | 2
abc | na3 | 3
def | na4 | 1
```

Now I want to update the `events.na` column with the values in `enrichments.na`, where `mac` matches, and `timestamp` is the maximum `timestamp` for that particular `mac`.

For this example, the result would be:

```
abc | na3
abc | na3
def | na4
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: That would be HyperSQL (HSQLDB).

Comment: Why do you have 2 identical rows in table `events`?

Comment: @ypercube: because I didn't include the columns that aren't identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE events AS e
SET na = 
    ( SELECT n.na
      FROM enrichments AS n
      WHERE n.mac = e.mac
      ORDER BY n.timestamp DESC
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the proper manual. I didn't see the comment clarifying the database system, as I was in the middle of writing my answer.

Comment: @AndriyM: Why did you delele your answer. It probably works fine.

Comment: Because it is essentially the same as yours, only I didn't know the right syntax (since I didn't know what product the OP was using). You've made a good job searching for the right manual, so your answer should stay.

Comment: Just noticed that you added *‘and `TOP`’* to the end of your comment to my answer. Sorry, but I couldn't find that in the manual you gave me the link to. FETCH FIRST and LIMIT are there, but TOP isn't. I might be looking [in the wrong place](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#dac_slicing), though.

Comment: @AndriyM: Yes, `LIMIT` and `FETCH` is mentioned in many places. `TOP` only once in paragraph: [Standards Support](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#sgc_standards). I wonder if it is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

this should work with SQL Server using a common table expression

```
create table events (mac nvarchar(3), na nvarchar(3))
insert into events values ('abc',null);
insert into events values ('abc',null);
insert into events values ('def',null);

create table enrichments (mac nvarchar(3), na nvarchar(3), timestamp int)
insert into enrichments values ('abc','na1',1)
insert into enrichments values ('abc','na2',2)
insert into enrichments values ('abc','na3',3)
insert into enrichments values ('def','na4',1)

with latestEnrichment (mac, latestTimestamp) as
    (select mac, MAX(timestamp)
    from    enrichments
    group by mac)
update  events
set     na = en.na
from    events e join enrichments en on e.mac = en.mac
        join latestEnrichment le on en.timestamp = le.latesttimestamp and
        en.mac = le.mac
```